# Is there any method to test two jobject are from the same class?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

For JNI, I have two jobject jobj1 and jobj2, how can I test that they are the instance of the same class?

I want to test whether two jobject jobj1 and jobj2 are the instance of the same class.

```
JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL TestTwoObjectEqual
    (JNIEnv *env, jclass jclazz, jobject jobj1, jobject jobj2);

I tried jclass cls_arraylist1 = env->GetObjectClass(jobj1); 
jclass cls_arraylist2 = env->GetObjectClass(jobj2);
```

Then compare *cls_arraylist1 == *cls_arraylist2, but == is not defined.

How can I test whether jobj1 and jobj2 are the instance of the same class of JAVA.

Comment: You can call [GetObjectClass](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#GetObjectClass) on both arguments and then compare returned values.

Comment: I tried jclass cls_arraylist1 = env->GetObjectClass(jobj1);
        jclass cls_arraylist2 = env->GetObjectClass(jobj2); Then compare *cls_arraylist1 == *cls_arraylist2, but == is not defined.

Comment: I think you can compare classes by pointers, no need to dereference. Or here is another solution: `IsInstanceOf(jobj2, GetObjectClass(jobj1)) && IsInstanceOf(jobj1, GetObjectClass(jobj2))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bool testTwoObjectEqual(JNIEnv *env, jobject jobj1, jobject jobj2) {
    jclass cls1 = env->GetObjectClass(jobj1);
    jclass cls2 = env->GetObjectClass(jobj2);
    bool res = env->IsInstanceOf(jobj1, cls2) && env->IsInstanceOf(jobj2, cls1);
    env->FreeLocalRef(cls1);
    env->FreeLocalRef(cls2);
    return res;
}
```

You can easily make this test less strict if **jobj2** may be *derived* from the class of **jobj1**. But maybe it's OK that both objects are *derived* from the same base class, e.g. from **java.util.ArrayList** — then you must supply this class to your test method.

If you want to know that **jobj1** and **jobj2** are **ArrayList**s of the same type, you must inspect the elements of these lists, because the information about the generics is compile-time only:

- check that jobj1 is instance of ArrayList
- check that jobj2 is instance of ArrayList
- get first non-null element of jobj1, jel1
- get first non-null element of jobj2, jel2
- check that class of jel1 is equal to class of jel2

**PS** I don't really understand why you want to use a dedicated native method for this task; as other (deleted) answers propose, this is a one-liner in Java, and they are easier to understand and have no performance concerns. This function is only relevant as a building block of a bigger JNI library, therefore you need to free all local references before return.